# ejabberd inter-module communication

Tags: erlang, ejabberd, ejabberd-module

I want to know if it is possible to obtain data of the other modules from a module. I am using ejabberd server 15.10, I implemented modules using Erlang.

Here is the case:

- I have a module that filters messages: **mod_filter**
- I have another module that makes some calculations while the server is running: **mod_calculate**

Is it possible to get fresh data from **mod_calculate** every time the ejabberd server filters a message at **mod_filter**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data isn't stored in modules but in variables. And you won't have access to internal variables on which code in one module operates without that that module exporting those variables to the external world somehow.

The module may have some functions already exported. Check with:

```
rp(mod_calculate:module_info()).
```

This will show you all functions exported in the module. Some of those functions may expose the variables from the module to other modules. If not, then you would need to add such functions and call them from `mod_filter`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

What @Amiramix states is accurate, but it's not the whole picture.

There's a low-coupling mechanism to communicate events between modules in ejabberd - it's the [hooks and handlers](http://mongooseim.readthedocs.org/en/latest/developers-guide/Hooks-and-handlers/) concept. The link points at MongooseIM documentation, but this mechanism is more or less the same in both codebases.

In general, one module can call a *hook*, which is alike a function call, but depending on the registered *handlers* may or may not result in some action(s) being carried out. Other modules can register handlers for hooks they choose. If you're authoring the modules in question, this is a mechanism which might give you the required communication channel.

To make things more concrete - each time `mod_filter` needs some information that only `mod_calculate` has access to, it can run `ejabberd_hooks:run_fold/4` with a custom hook name. If `mod_calculate` registers a handler for that hook (usually in its `start` function), it can return some data relevant to `mod_filter`. However, different modules can implement a handler for the hook, so `mod_filter` and `mod_calculate` aren't coupled as they would be if you used a direct function call (like `mod_calculate:some_function(...)`).